# Is this use of case statement a bad practice?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have some code like this:

```
case Product.new.class # ActiveRecord instance class => Product
when Module
  'this condition will always be true'
when Product
  'i need this to be true, but first condition is always true, so it never happens'
end
```

Here, `when Module` is always `true`. Why? Is this unexpected behaviour?

Comment: what is `something`?

Comment: something what can `respond_to?(:class)`

Comment: Your assertion is not true then if the only constraint is that the object has to respond to `class`.  I can easily create an object that defines its own `class` method, and from that method I can return anything I want.   It doesn't have to be a `Class` or a `Module`, it could be any arbitrary Ruby object.  I think if people ask what the scope is, then you should say you are only talking about objects who don't override the `class` method, and thus they are using `Kernel#class`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, such a seemingly simple queston.  But is it?

Here `Product` is some class, say:

```
Product = Class.new
```

Since

```
Product.new.class
  #=> Product
```

your case statement can be simplified to

```
case Product
when Module
  'this condition will always be true'
when Product
  'i need this to be true, so it never happens'
end
```

Recall that the `case` statement uses the method `===` to determine which object to return, meaning that your `case` statement is equivalent to

```
if Module === Product
  'this condition will always be true'
elsif Product === Product
  'i need this to be true, so it never happens'
end
```

Let's see how the two logical expressions evaluate:

```
Module  === Product  #=> true 
Product === Product  #=> false
```

Note this is syntactic sugar for

```
Module.===(Product)  #=> true
Product.===(Product) #=> false
```

Examine the docs for the method [Module#===](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) to see how it works: it returns `true` if `Product` is an instance of `Module` or of one of `Module`'s descendents.  Well, is it?

```
Product.class   #=> Class 
Class.ancestors #=> [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

It is! Now what about:

```
Product === Product
```

Does `Product` have a method `===`?:

```
Product.methods.include?(:===)
  #=> true
```

Where did it come from (we didn't define it, after all)? Let's first look at:

```
Product.ancestors
  #=> [Product, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Does `Object` have a method `===`? Checking the docs we see that it does:  [Object#===](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D).<sup>1</sup>

So `Object#===` is invoked. Right? Let's just confirm that:

```
Product.method(:===).owner
  #=> Module
```

Whoops! It comes from `Module` (which is both a module and a class), not from `Object`. As we saw above, `Product` is an instance of `Class` and `Class` is a subclass of `Module`.  Note also that here `===` is an instance method of `Class` (and of `Module`)<sup>2</sup>:

```
Class.instance_method(:===).owner
  #=> Module
```

So `Product` is in a quandary. Should it use `Module#===`, an instance method supplied by it's parent (`Class`), who inherited it from `Module`, or should it go with `Object#===`, that it inherits from its superclass, `Object`? The answer is that precedence is with the former.

This is at the heart of Ruby's "object model". I will say no more about that, but I hope I have provided readers with some tools they can use to figure out what's going on (e.g., [Object#method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-method) and [Method#owner](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Method.html#method-i-owner).

Since `Product === Product` uses `Module#===` just as `Module == Product` does, we determine if the former returns `true` by answering the question, " is `Product` an instance of `Product` or of one of `Product`'s decendents?". Product has no descendents and

```
Product.class #=> Class,
```

so the answer is "no", meaning `Product === Product` returns `false`.

**Edit:** I see I forgot to actually answer the question posed in the title. This calls for an opinion I suppose (a SO no-no), but I think `case` statements are the greatest thing since sliced bread. They are particularly useful when one needs to compare various values to a reference value (e.g., the contents of a variable or to a value returned by a method) using `===` or `==`. For example (see [Fixnum#===](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D), where `===` is equivalent to `==`--note the typo in the docs, [Regexp#===](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) and [Range#===](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D)):

```
str =
case x
when 1                   then 'cat'
when 2,3                 then 'dog'
when (5..Float#INFINITY) then 'cow'
else                          'pig'
end

result =
case obj
when String
  ...
when Array
  ...
end

case str
when /\d/
  ...
when /[a-z]/
  ...
end
```

Beyond that, however, I often use a `case statement` in place of `if..elsif..else..end` just because I think it`s tidier and more esthetically pleasing:

```
case
when time == 5pm
  feed the dog
when day == Saturday
  mow the lawn
...
end
```

<sup>1 In fact, this method is available to all objects, but is not generally
invoked because the method is also defined for a descendant.</sup>

<sup>2 To be thoroughly confusing, Class also has a triple-equals class method:
`Class.method(:===).owner #=> Module`.</sup>

Comment: @BorisStitnicky, I am reminded of [this](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=CJwgcZbc2ks), around 2:30.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug.  In Ruby, the class whose name is `Class` is a subclass of the class whose name is `Module`.  Every instance of `Class` is therefore also a `Module`.

This is documented here, in the left column where it says "Parent":

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Class.html

You asked if this is a bad practice.  Yes.  It is a bad practice because the first case in your case statement is guaranteed to run, so it means that all the other cases of the case statement are unreachable code that can never run.  Unreachable code is a bad practice.  It would be better to write your code like this:

```
case something
when Product
  # we know that it is a Product
when Customer
  # we know that it is a Customer
else
  # handle other cases
end
```

## Tangential comment

It is very weird that you are showing us some code that does not work, and then asking if it is a "bad practice".  Obviously the code is a bad practice if it doesn't work at all in any situations!  You need to first get your code to work.  After it is working, you can try to think about different versions of the code and evaluate each one to see if it is "bad practice" or "good practice", but that assumes that those different versions actually work.

**Suppose you had instead asked how to write a method in Ruby that multiplies a number by 4.**

Here is some code that doesn't work, so we won't even discuss if it is bad practice or not:

```
def foo(x)
  x * 3
end
```

Here is some code that works, but it is bad practice in all kinds of ways:

```
def foo(x)
return x + x+ x + x - x + x*1
end
```

Here is some code that works, and is good practice:

```
def foo(x)
  x * 4
end
```

Comment: Why, then, would `"".is_a?(Module)` be false?

Comment: `""` is not a class, it is an empty string.  `"".class` is a `Class`, and it is also a `Module`.

Comment: but if i need to compare my condition class with something more specific. like AR `Product.new.class (#=>Product)` it has to be true only if  `== Product`, isn't it?

Comment: @okliv I don't understand what you are asking now.  I think I answered your original question sufficiently, so it would be nice if you could mark it as the accepted answer.  If you want to post a new, separate question about ActiveRecord, that is fine.  Just be sure to explain exactly what your situation is and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm taking a wild guess, but maybe the code you are looking for is simply this: https://gist.github.com/DavidEGrayson/a86a83dcc72d57e8d57e

Comment: @DavidGrayson, i edited my question. it was moderated by someone and too simplified so my comment became not clear

Comment: thanks for an answer, it points to the core of problem, but the question is more about "is this a bad practice?" to compare objects like Module instead of, for example, ....to_s'ed strings (like i did when found this case) if this is not a bug (like you said)

Comment: sorry man, but looks like you do not try to even get what am i asking about... maybe you have more skills in ruby than me but "multiplies a number by 4"... really? you think i am so stupid? or you smarter than me? @Cary is answered much more interesting and clever (and targeted me to what i am asking about)... if you think the question is stupid, then why do you even try to answer? just make -1 and do not spend time on it... and you cant name question as unclear because Carry, again, answered what i asked... and you just tried to show your excellence, nothing else

Comment: In my "Tangential comment", I wasn't teaching you how to multiply by 4, I was verbosely explaining why it is strange to ask about good practice and bad practice for code that doesn't work at all yet, and showing some examples.

Comment: Come on @okliv, you totally misunderstood the point I was making, got mad, and you made no effort to understand my point after I explained it.  Do you really think I was teaching you how to multiply by 4 or implying that you are stupid?  Do you understand that the discussion of good practices and bad practices is usually applied to code that at least partially works?  Did I not answer your original question?